# Set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet only happens on combo and dropdown boxes?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-combobox

I have a MVC4 .net app using Kendo UI. I get the set jsonrequestbehavior issue for comboboxes and dropdowns but not listview when they all use the same function to read. I want to populate a dropdown box. Am I missing something?
Relevant Code:

relevant part of the cshtml(view):

```
        <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="propertiestemplate">
            <div class="partnersss">
                <h5>#:PartnerID#</h5>
                <p>#:PartnerName#</p>
            </div>
        </script>
        <div class="editor-field">
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("partnerddl")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 250px" })
            .DataTextField("PartnerName")
            .DataValueField("PartnerID")
            .AutoBind(true)
            .DataSource(source => {
            source.Read(read =>
            {

                read.Action("GetPropertyPartners", "Property", new { onlyActive = true });
            }); 
            })
        )
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
            .Name("partnercb")
            .Placeholder("Select Partner...")
            .DataTextField("PartnerName")
            .DataValueField("PartnerID")
            .AutoBind(true)
            .Filter("contains")
            .MinLength(3)
            .DataSource(source => {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("GetPropertyPartners", "Property", new { onlyActive = true });
            }).ServerFiltering(true); 
            })
        )
        @(Html.Kendo().ListView<MyVegas.Rewards.Nucleus.Entities.PropertyPartnerView>()
        .Name("partnerlv")
        .TagName("div")
        .ClientTemplateId("propertiestemplate")
        .DataSource(ds => ds
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetPropertyPartners", "Property", new { onlyActive = true }))
        )
        )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartnerID)
    </div>
```

controller:

```
    public JsonResult GetPropertyPartners([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest, bool onlyActive)
    {
        partners = property.GetPartnersForProperties(onlyActive);
        var result = partners.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest);
        return Json(result);
    }
```

## Result  Protocol    Host            URL                                             Body    Caching Content-Type                        Process

27  500     HTTP        localhost:2590  /Property/GetPropertyPartners?onlyActive=True   8,783   private text/html; charset=utf-8            iexplore:17452
28  500     HTTP        localhost:2590  /Property/GetPropertyPartners?onlyActive=True   8,783   private text/html; charset=utf-8            iexplore:17452
29  200     HTTP        localhost:2590  /Property/GetPropertyPartners?onlyActive=True   132     private application/json; charset=utf-8     iexplore:17452

number 27 and 28 give this json back(incorrect):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.InvalidOperationException: This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[InvalidOperationException: This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.]
   System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +362369
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1a.&lt;InvokeActionResultWithFilters&gt;b__17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1c.&lt;InvokeActionResultWithFilters&gt;b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass2a.&lt;BeginInvokeAction&gt;b__20() +89
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass25.&lt;BeginInvokeAction&gt;b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1d.&lt;BeginExecuteCore&gt;b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass8.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9628700
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +155
</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18044

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[InvalidOperationException]: This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.
   at System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->
```

number 29 gives this json back(correct):

```
{"Data":[{"PartnerID":1,"PartnerName":"test1"},{"PartnerID":2,"PartnerName":"test2"}],"Total":2,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null}
```

Comment: I have tried setting serverfiltering to true and false on both the combobox and dropdown.

Comment: http://imgur.com/sGUouLZ there is the image of what it looks like since i dont have 10 rep points to attach images.

Comment: Also to note i have tried changing return Json(result); to return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); it still has an issue this time it returns the correct json but it doesnt fill the dropdown or combobox.

Comment: I have the solution but it says i cant answer my own question for 8 hours until then here is the solution will repost as answer:
Changed
public JsonResult GetPropertyPartners([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest, bool onlyActive)
{
partners = property.GetPartnersForProperties(onlyActive);
var result = partners.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest);
return Json(result);
}
to
public JsonResult GetPropertyPartners([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest, bool onlyActive)
{
partners = property.GetPartnersForProperties(onlyActive);
return Json(partners, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

Answer (score 0):

Reposting Tom Maxwell's comment as answer.

Changed:

```
public JsonResult GetPropertyPartners([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest, bool onlyActive) 
{ 
     partners = property.GetPartnersForProperties(onlyActive); 
     var result = partners.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest); 
     return Json(result); 
}
```

to:

```
public JsonResult GetPropertyPartners([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest, bool onlyActive) 
{ 
          partners = property.GetPartnersForProperties(onlyActive); 
          return Json(partners, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```